# Are there any physics equations that involve exponents >= 5?

Tags: laws-of-physics

This might be a strange physics question, but I am curious about it. **Are there any physics equations that involve exponents $\geq$ 5?**

There are plenty of equations with **square exponents**. Inverse square laws are the most obvious to me, like the universal gravitational force law. $$ F = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

I've seen some equations with an **exponent of 3**, like [power to overcome drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Power) in a fluid:

$$ P = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^3 A C_d $$

And also various cube-square laws like the semi-major axis related to the [orbital period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period):

$$ a^3 = \frac{GMT^2}{4\pi^2} $$

I've also seen an equation with an **exponent of 4**. It's the [Luminosity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity) for black bodies, usually used for star luminosity: $$ L = \sigma A T^4 $$

There are also various [beam-deflection formulas](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/beam-stress-deflection-d_1312.html) involving the 4th power of length, like a simple beam supported at both ends:

$$ \delta _{max} = \frac{5qL^4}{384EI} $$

But that might be considered more engineering than physics.

Anyway, I have never seen a physics equation involving an exponent of 5 or more. Do they exist? Is there some reason why they are super-rare or non-existent?

Admittedly, there is some arbitrariness in this question. For example, we could take any law we want, like Hookes Law, and take both sides to the 5th power...

$$ F = -kx $$

$$ F^5 = -k^5x^5 $$

But that's way too arbitrary. I guess the best way to avoid that is to say we want a physics equation in its most simple or most useful form.

Also, you could say that the hypervolume of a cube in 5 dimensions is equal to $x^5$. That is a little too arbitrary too. Not even sure if that's physics or just plain geometry.

Comment: A spring force can be proportional to $F=k\,x^5$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential there certainly are, but this has been asked before https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508797/23615

Comment: One of the critical exponents in the 2D Ising model is 15.

Comment: Does Cauchy's relation count?

Comment: Electric fields of octupole and higher multipole charge distributions have inverse distance exponents $\ge 5$. Single-particle nuclear model multipole gamma energy transition probabilitiy in nuclei of quadrupole and higher are proportional to $E^5$ or greater.

Comment: The Planck law wrt lambda^5